Force acting on a continuous body distributes evenly?
Consider the following scenario.
I have a cylinder with cross sectional radius $d$, uniform mass density $\rho$ throughout out the length, with a total mass $m$. Suppose that a force $F$ is acting perpendicularly outwards to the area of cross section from one direction. Consider two small volume elements having length $dx$. Which are at a distance $x$ and $y$,  $(x≠y)$ from the point of application of force. Does these area elements experience is the same force?

My answer is No.
And an Example I can give is, consider the following string mass system alternatively with massless inextensible string and each block has same mass. If I insert a massless force gauge in between the first two masses and the last two masses. Then on the application of force $F$ first device will show the reading for which it has to pull 5 such masses, on the other hand the last device will pull only 1 such mass. Then obvious answer is the first device will show more reading then the device at the end. If I am right till now.
Then I wanted to extend this analogy for continuous mass system. Consider the above cylindrical object that is under action of force $F$. A small volume element having mass $dm$ of length $dx$ which is at a distance of $x$ units from the point of application of force..
Then the small force $dF$ acting on it is given by second law of motion:
$$ dF = dm×a $$
Where $a$ is the same acceleration by which the whole body is accelerating due to the applied force $F$.
We know mass is equal to density$×$volume. So, $$dF = \rho πr^2×dx×a$$
The force which is acting at a point which is at a distance $x$, has to pull all the weight which is after it, so the limits for $dx$ will very from $x$ to total length of the cylinder. (And I am not sure what to put the limit for $dF$, but somehow I understand after integration it will give the total force that is acting at that point - fundamental theorem of integral calculus).
$$\int dF = \rho πr^2 a\int_x^l dx $$
$$F' = \rho \pi r^2 a(l-x)$$
And this answer feels right to me because the force at the point of application of force is maximum.  And zero at the last point.So, that cylinder will experience different forces at different positions.

Is everything fine whatever I have done? And need explanation for integration part.


Applying Newton’s 2nd and 3rd laws to each section will tell you the answer is no

How is this not a check-my-work question?

@VincentThacker {Underlying Physics Concepts}  $ \cap $  {check my work} ≠ $ \phi $

Are you considering static or dynamic conditions?
If the structural element is accelerating (or some part of it are accelerating), the axial force is not constant through the span of the beam. The governing equation for small strains, is
$$m \partial_{tt} d - \partial_{x} N = f \ ,$$
with the proper initial and boundary conditions and the constitutive law connecting the axial force $N$ with the strain, usually for an elastic beam $EA \partial_x d$, with $d(x,t)$ the displacement of the points of the beam, and $f(x,t)$ the force per unit length.
If there's no acceleration, by equilibrium, the axial force is constant through the span. As you can see, if acceleration is zero for each point, $\partial_{tt} d \equiv 0$, if there's no distributed loads $f(x,t) \equiv 0$, thus $\partial_x N = 0$, i.e. the axial force is uniform along the span, and equals the applied forces at the extreme points of the beam, for the equilibrium.

Thanks sir, but was not aware that this concept is going towards some engineering problem. I haven't studied this all. However this question is already been closed, I would be thankful if you could suggest me some study material for this all. And I don't even know, whether asking for study material is within the rules of this site or not :) Thanks in advance.

You could start from this hand-written notes https://basics.altervista.org/test/Physics/CM/structure_mechanics/main.html

I don't know your proficiency in math and physics, but if you're quite good at tech university level, BSc or MSc, these could be good for you
